# Multiple selection in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I work on a new project that need a multiple row selection/deselection by the user in a datagridview with only a tap on a touch screen.

The form should look like this:

[image: Form Screenshot]

For exemple, if the user want to delete row 2 and 5, he only need to tap once on each line to select/deselect them.  After the selection is done, he tap on "Delete Row" button.

I've already try to play with the CellClick event without success!!

Can someone have a clue how can I handle this problem?

Comment: That would typically be a function of the grid's normal behavior, and done by holding CTRL as you left click the row headers.  A grid property probably controls the selection type.

Comment: Since no keyboard will be present for the operator I want a fonction that "emulate" the CTRL key!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting `MultiSelect` property to `True` and `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect` you can use a `List` to store which row of your `DataGridView` is selected.

On `CellClick` you can add/remove rows from your `List`, on `RowPostPaint` you can select a row if it's included in the `List` and on `RowsRemoved` you have to clear the `List`.

```
Private intSelectedRows As New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

    With CType(sender, DataGridView)

        Dim intRow As Integer = .CurrentRow.Index

        If Not Me.intSelectedRows.Contains(intRow) Then
            Me.intSelectedRows.Add(intRow)
        Else
            .CurrentRow.Selected = False
            Me.intSelectedRows.Remove(intRow)
        End If

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPostPaint

    If Me.intSelectedRows.Contains(e.RowIndex) Then
        CType(sender, DataGridView).Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsRemoved(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsRemoved

    Me.intSelectedRows.Clear()

End Sub
```

If you want to clear selection you can use this code:

```
Private Sub btnClearSelectedRows_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClearSelectedRows.Click

    For Each intSelectedRow As Integer In Me.intSelectedRows
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(intSelectedRow).Selected = False
    Next intSelectedRow

    Me.intSelectedRows.Clear()

End Sub
```

Comment: Work like a charm!!  Exactly what I looking for! 
Thank you so much @tezzo

Comment: Just tested a little more, but I run into an issue.  If I want to clear the selection made by this method, how can I proceed, except reclick on all row already selected!?  I've tried clearselection but without success.

Comment: Again, work like a charm.  Little struggle in the first test since I forgot to erase the previous code for that button.